# how to create when the user click on products in left side details will be shown in right side

Tags: javascript, html

i have 6 products in left side div...when i click on product-1 only product-descript-1(details of product-1) will be shown in right side div and remaining details  of products are hidden....
if i click on product-2 then only product-descript-2 (details of second product) is shown in the right side
and  product-3 and prodcut4 and product-5 and product-6 are aslo same way

```js
//actually i have 40 products

//suggest simple code 
//instead of using this script any other simple way


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
      $("#product-1").click(function(){
           $("#product-descript1").show()
           $("#product-descript2,#product-descript3,#product-descript4,#product-descript5,#product-descript6).hide()
       });
       
 }
 </script>
```

```css
#product-descript2,#product-descript3,#product-descript4,#product-descript5,#product-descript6{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
 <title>products</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/xzoom.css">
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.elevatezoom.js"></script> -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/xzoom.min.js"></script>

 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--left div-->

<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
         <div class="card" id="product-1">
            <div class="pic">
               <img class="product-img" src="images/t-shirt-1.jpg">
            </div><!--pic-->
              <div class="pic-body">
                <p>maniac mens cottton T-shirt</p>
                  <h5>RS-399</h5>
              </div><!--pic-body-->
         </div><!--card-->
     </div><!--md-4-->
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
         <div class="card" id="product-2">
             <div class="pic">
              <img class="product-img" src="images/t-shirt-2.jpg">
             </div><!--pic-->
              <div class="pic-body">
                <p>maniac mens cottton T-shirt</p>
                <h5>RS-399</h5>
                </div><!--pic-body-->
         </div><!--card-->
      </div><!--md-4-->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
          <div class="card" id="product-3">
             <div class="pic">
                <img class="product-img" src="images/t-shirt-3.jpg">
             </div><!--pic-->
             <div class="pic-body">
                <p>maniac mens cottton T-shirt</p>
                <h5>RS-399</h5>
             </div><!--pic-body-->
          </div><!--card-->
      </div><!--md-4-->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
          <div class="card" id="product-4">
              <div class="pic">
               <img class="product-img" src="images/t-shirt-4.jpg">
             </div><!--pic-->
             <div class="pic-body">
                <p>maniac mens cottton T-shirt</p>
                <h5>RS-399</h5>
              </div><!--pic-body-->
          </div><!--card-->
      </div><!--md-4-->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
          <div class="card" id="product-5">
             <div class="pic">
              <img class="product-img" src="images/t-shirt-5.jpg">
             </div><!--pic-->
             <div class="pic-body">
                <p>maniac mens cottton T-shirt</p>
                <h5>RS-399</h5>
             </div><!--pic-body-->
          </div><!--card-->
      </div><!--md-4-->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
          <div class="card" id="product-6">
             <div class="pic">
              <img class="product-img" src="images/t-shirt-6.jpg">
             </div><!--pic-->
             <div class="pic-body">
                <p>maniac mens cottton T-shirt</p>
                <h5>RS-399</h5>
             </div><!--pic-body-->
         </div><!--card-->
      </div><!--md-4-->
   </div><!--lg-8-->
   
   
   <!--right-div-->
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
   
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" id="product-descript1">
         <div class="product-img">
              <img src="images/bt-shirt-1.jpg">
          </div><!--product-img-->
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-center btns">
       <button class="btn btn-success buy-btn"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag btn-symbol"></i>Buy Now</button>
    </div><!--md-6-->
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center btns">
       <button class="btn btn-success buy-btn"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down btn-symbol"></i>Add To Cart</button>
    </div><!--md-6-->
  <div><!--md-12-->
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" id="product-descript2">
         <div class="product-img">
              <img src="images/bt-shirt-2.jpg">
          </div><!--product-img-->
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-center btns">
       <button class="btn btn-success buy-btn"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag btn-symbol"></i>Buy Now</button>
    </div><!--md-6-->
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center btns">
       <button class="btn btn-success buy-btn"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down btn-symbol"></i>Add To Cart</button>
    </div><!--md-6-->
  <div><!--md-12-->
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" id="product-descript3">
         <div class="product-img">
              <img src="images/bt-shirt-3.jpg">
          </div><!--product-img-->
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-center btns">
       <button class="btn btn-success buy-btn"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag btn-symbol"></i>Buy Now</button>
    </div><!--md-6-->
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center btns">
       <button class="btn btn-success buy-btn"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down btn-symbol"></i>Add To Cart</button>
    </div><!--md-6-->
  <div><!--md-12-->
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" id="product-descript4">
         <div class="product-img">
              <img src="images/bt-shirt-4.jpg">
          </div><!--product-img-->
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-center btns">
       <button class="btn btn-success buy-btn"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag btn-symbol"></i>Buy Now</button>
    </div><!--md-6-->
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center btns">
       <button class="btn btn-success buy-btn"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down btn-symbol"></i>Add To Cart</button>
    </div><!--md-6-->
  <div><!--md-12-->
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" id="product-descript5">
         <div class="product-img">
              <img src="images/bt-shirt-5.jpg">
          </div><!--product-img-->
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-center btns">
       <button class="btn btn-success buy-btn"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag btn-symbol"></i>Buy Now</button>
    </div><!--md-6-->
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center btns">
       <button class="btn btn-success buy-btn"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down btn-symbol"></i>Add To Cart</button>
    </div><!--md-6-->
  <div><!--md-12-->
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" id="product-descript6">
         <div class="product-img">
              <img src="images/bt-shirt-6.jpg">
          </div><!--product-img-->
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-center btns">
       <button class="btn btn-success buy-btn"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag btn-symbol"></i>Buy Now</button>
    </div><!--md-6-->
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center btns">
       <button class="btn btn-success buy-btn"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down btn-symbol"></i>Add To Cart</button>
    </div><!--md-6-->
  <div><!--md-12-->
  
  
</div><!--lg-4-->

   





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean you want to to show the currently clicked item and hide the rest of the products ?

Comment: yeah exactly bro

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Comment: you might have missed some tag somewhere, because there is an error that is being thrown in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's e simple example how to get this done using JavaScript:

```js
let i, products = document.getElementsByClassName('product'); // get all products

for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  products[i].onclick = function() {
    showInfo(this.id)
  }; // add onclick Event to all products
}

function showInfo(id) {
  let x, infos = document.getElementsByClassName('info'); // get all infos
  for (x = 0; x < infos.length; x++) {
    (infos[x].id === 'info-' + id) ? infos[x].className = 'info': infos[x].className = 'info hidden'; // Show info for clicked product only
  }
}
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.products {
  width: 140px;
}

.infos {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
}

.product {
  background: grey;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}

.info {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="products">
    <div class="product" id="product1">
      Product 1
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="product2">
      Product 2
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="product3">
      Product 3
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="product4">
      Product 4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="infos">
    <div class="info" id="info-product1">
      Info 1
    </div>
    <div class="info hidden" id="info-product2">
      Info 2
    </div>
    <div class="info hidden" id="info-product3">
      Info 3
    </div>
    <div class="info hidden" id="info-product4">
      Info 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use class selector so you can target all the products, for example you can use add `class="product"` to each product div (at the same level as product-ID ) then once the user clicks on any item with that class hide all the items with that class and show only the currently clicked one.

Here is a simple complete working solution:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product" id="product_1">
    <b>product1</b>
    <p class="details">details</p>
</div>
<div class="product" id="product_2">
    <b>product2</b>
    <p class="details">details</p>
</div>
<div class="product" id="product_3">
    <b>product3</b>
    <p class="details">details</p>
</div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.product').on('click',function(e){
            $('.details').hide();
            $(this).find('.details').show();
        });
    });

</script>
```

Try to understand this solution and let me know if something is unclear,
Otherwise if you find it helpful don't forget to accept this answer.

Comment: but i want all the product are in left side and all the details are in right side

Comment: No problem just when you click on a single product, get its specific data and show it in the left area.

Comment: I think it is simple, another note please try to put a small working piece of code when asking questions, this way people can answer your question without wasting a lot of time.

Comment: no bro  ...in my code..all the products are in one div and all the details are in another div

Comment: Ok, no problem you still can use this logic.
for example for product id use `product_1` and for the description id use `product_1_description` so when you click on the product with id `product_1` you can programatically get that id and add to it `_description` and you get `product_1_description` that you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

A simple working solution could to load a file into a `<div>`.

See below snippet. This calls an external file from your directory to be set into the `<div class="Product"></div>`. I have already set a filepath there via SSI so there will be content then on load (maybe content telling the user to select a product in the menu).

The menu could be anything - images, text etc. - I have just used text for this example.

For this to adjust your needs your need to edit this:

- `Product1`: Change this to your unique ID you use in the menu.
- `DivToContent`: Change this to the CLASS-name of the `<div>` you want your content.
- `PathTo/File1.html`: Change this to the path of your file.
- `charset=ISO-8859-1`: Change this to the [charset](https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html_charset.asp) your use

I have not provided any CSS as you may style all classes as you wish. All ID-tags are for scripts only. This can be provided with a neat transition if you want that.

For more products than six, just copy/paste below and edit the numbers.

```
  $('#Product1').click(function(e) {
    $('.DivToContent').load('PathTo/File1.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#Product1').click(function(e) {
    $('.DivToContent').load('PathTo/File1.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#Product2').click(function(e) {
    $('.DivToContent').load('PathTo/File2.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#Product3').click(function(e) {
    $('.DivToContent').load('PathTo/File3.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#Product4').click(function(e) {
    $('.DivToContent').load('PathTo/File4.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#Product5').click(function(e) {
    $('.DivToContent').load('PathTo/File5.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('#Product6').click(function(e) {
    $('.DivToContent').load('PathTo/File6.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

$.ajaxSetup({
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
  }
});

// Handler to wrap a SPAN around what is selected
$(document).on('click', '.DivMenu a', function(e) {
  $('.DivMenu .productselected a').unwrap(  )
  $(this).wrap("<span class='productselected'></span>");
  
});
```

```html
<div class="DivMenu">
<p>
<a id="Product1" href="javascript:;">Product1</a> &#124; 
<a id="Product2" href="javascript:;">Product2</a> &#124; 
<a id="Product3" href="javascript:;">Product3</a> &#124; 
<a id="Product4" href="javascript:;">Product4</a> &#124; 
<a id="Product5" href="javascript:;">Product5</a> &#124; 
<a id="Product6" href="javascript:;">Product6</a>
</p>
</div>

<div class="DivToContent"><!--#include virtual="PathTo/File0.html"--></div>
```